# How can i get the age of a person with the Date of birth in pl/sql or sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

This is my table.

```
create table ator(
numero_identidade varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
numero_ss varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
dt_nascimento date NOT NULL,
nacionalidade varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
nome_artistico varchar2(40),
sexo char(1) NOT NULL,
idade number(2,0) NOT NULL,
primary key (numero_identidade),
CONSTRAINT sexo_a check (sexo = 'F' or sexo = 'M'));
```

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(idade,GETDATE())/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc
```

i have've seen this command on the internet but i don't understand how to use it.

how can i do that??

Comment: What DBMS is this for? Oracle? Please add the correct tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Oracle DBMS try with:

```
SELECT TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, dt_nascimento)/12) AS idade FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you saw:

```
> DATEDIFF(hour,idade,GETDATE())/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc
```

It takes the difference in hours and divide it by the number of hours in a year: 365.25*24 = 8766.
That means you end up having the age in years.
Hope this help.
.
Just try

```
select DATEDIFF(hour,idade,GETDATE())/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc
from ator
```

Comment: well now i understand what it does but i cant put it to work :(